# Cuando retorno mi json de un echo en php no me lo toma mi llamada ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Actualmente quiero hacer la funcionalidad de un login con ajax y php pero la situacion es que no funciona de forma correcta:

Script de Jquery:

```
<script>

        $(document).on('submit', "#frmLogin", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({  
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: "post",  
                 dataType: 'json',
                data: {$(this).serialize()+","+NameEnviar:"Acceder"},
                error:function(){
                    alert("ERROR : CANNOT CONNECT TO SERVER");

                },
                success: function(data) {
                   alert(data);

                }
            });
            return false; 
        });

</script>
```

Codigo de Php:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $return_arr[] = array("data" => 1);
 echo json_encode($return_arr); 
 /* close connection */
mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
        $return_arr[] = array("data" => 0);
  echo json_encode($return_arr); 
  /* close connection */
mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

El punto es que si me realiza el echo en mi ventana `[{"data":0}]` pero ese echo aparece en una ventana en blanco con la dirección que le di en el post a mi formulario, pero lo que quiero es que la ventana no cambie y el echo lo imprima en mi console.log.

Comment: Puedes compartir el html de tu formulario para un mejor entendimiento?. Para que no muestre el resultado en otra página no debes usar el submit, en su lugar agrega un input tipo button y a ese botón asocia el evento jquery.

Comment: Está bien que tengas un `onSubmit` en el formulario. Pero algo no te está tomando bien, publicá el HTML. Ahora, data lo estás definiendo mal, sacá las llaves, debería ser algo así: `$(this).serialize() + '&NameEnviar=Acceder'`. Está bien que uses las llaves para definir un objeto, pero `serialize()` te devuelve un string, estás mezclado las cosas.